# Calculating the distance of items from non-empty edges in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have a matrix of 0 and 1

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

I want to calculate the shortest distance of each item from the non-empty edges. You can assume it as pixels of black and white (or empty). We want to calculate the distance of each black pixel from the edge of the black body (through a straight line; horizontal, vertical or diagonal).

The distance is calculated geometrically: the distance of A<sub>i,j</sub> and A<sub>i+1,j+1</sub> is `sqrt(2)`.

With the following code in C, I started to calculate the distance of each item from its horizontal and vertical edges (in four directions). Now I want to consider diagonal distance too (at any angle, not just 45°).

The straightforward approach is to calculate the distance of each item from each edge. However, as the matrix gets larger, the loops become painfully slow.

Since we have the distance from horizontal and vertical edges for each item, I look for a hack to find the shortest distance to the edge by examining neighbour items in fewer checks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int e = a < b ? a : b;
    int f = c < d ? c : d;
    int r = e < f ? e : f;
    return r;
}

int main()
{

    int width = 50;
    int height = 50;
    int points[width][height];
    int distances[width][height][5]; // 0 left 1 right 2 bottom 3 top 4 min

    // some random data
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            points[x][y] = rand() % 2;
        }
    }

    // scanning in four direction to check if the previous neighbour exists
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    distances[x][y][0] = distances[x - 1][y][0] > 0 ? distances[x - 1][y][0] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][0] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (x < width - 1)
                {
                    distances[x][y][1] = distances[x + 1][y][1] > 0 ? distances[x + 1][y][1] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (y > 0)
                {
                    distances[x][y][2] = distances[x][y - 1][2] > 0 ? distances[x][y - 1][2] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][2] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (y < height - 1)
                {
                    distances[x][y][3] = distances[x][y + 1][3] > 0 ? distances[x][y + 1][3] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][3] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // finding the minimum of four distances
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                distances[x][y][4] = min(distances[x][y][0], distances[x][y][1], distances[x][y][2], distances[x][y][3]);
                printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d \n", x, y, distances[x][y][0], distances[x][y][1], distances[x][y][2], distances[x][y][3], distances[x][y][4]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this distance is known as the *Euclidean distance*, or *L2-norm*. Those are unambiguous.

Comment: and you can calculate euclidian distance using your horizontal and vertical distances, through pythagorean theorem (which is the 2d version of the distance formula)

Comment: What do you mean by the loops being too long? Computationally expensive, too much code or maybe both?

Comment: @JardelLucca the former, computationally expensive. Code is the same.

Comment: @Rogue I know how to calculate the distance with the Pythagorean theorem. I want to minimise the number of calculations.

Comment: The loops become slow because you're introducing an intractable problem: you're performing in the "best-worst" case `n(n+1)/2` distance calculations for every `n` nodes in your matrix. With some assumptions about distance between nodes you can reduce that number, but if that distance varies that's the objective minimum you could ever hit. You could save some computation by not calculating "backwards" (e.g. B->A, as A->B would already be calculated), since that's locking you at `n(n+1)` caculations atm

Comment: @Rogue you're referring to the loops in the code. They are fast enough (just four loops). I meant the next step. Calculating the distance between each item and all edges found (every point with `distances[x][y][0] == 1 || distances[x][y][1] == 1 || distances[x][y][2] == 1 || distances[x][y][3] == 1`). There will be thousands of additional loops. I want to use the available distances for the neighbour items to avoid checking the distance with each edge.

Comment: @Rogue by the way, how do you calculate the distance from the right without a backward loop?

Comment: I think the problem is very clear now. And it's an interesting one.

Comment: One way wouuld be an adjacency matrix (which will be a large memory footprint, `n^4`), so as to track the distance calulations as they're performed. From there, you merely check if a distance already exists between two nodes. If you already calculated A->B, then B->A is no different and can just be looked up.

Comment: @Rogue I still don't get it. In the range of A ... B ... C; we want the distance of B from A and C (two edges). We count from A to reach B. Then we count from C to reach B (distances from the left and right). When reaching B, we still do not know the position of C. Therefore, we need the backward scan (even for inserting the value read from an adjacency matrix).

Comment: My suggestion would have you start with point `(0,0)`, calculating the distances to _every_ other point in the matrix. Then you move to the next point `(0,1)`, calculating distances to _every_ point _except_ `(0, 0)`, as that can be referenced from the calculation of `(0, 0)` to `(0, 1)` (which was done already). That adjacency matrix would have an entry in (roughly): `[(0,0)] [(0,1)]`, which you know to reference as it would have been "previously visited", keeping in mind to reduce the pairs to single scalar values. What you trade off in memory usage is gained in less computations.

Comment: @Rogue Correct me if I'm wrong. For a matrix of 1000X1000, we need 1,000,000 x 500,000 calculations. The structure of the adjacency matrix will be adjacency[1000000][1000000] array. This is the most expensive solution I know.

Comment: @Googlebot `int points[width][height] = { 0 };` is invalid C.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right. It was my mistake. It doesn't work with variable-sized objects. I fixed it. Since 0 will be assigned in the loop, it was not important and I had not changed it in my running code.

Comment: Do you consider an *edge* every non empty pixel surrounded by at least an empty (zero) one and *distance* as the Euclidean distance between the centers of two pixels or the edge is the immaginary line between a 1 and a 0 pixel?

Comment: @Bob__ both should work, as the difference is just 0.5 unit/pixel difference. The key point is the fastest algorithm.

Comment: @Googlebot, Are any holes inside the black body allowed? Or can we just assume it as one continuous surface without any holes?

Comment: @Googlebot Your code to randomly fill the array allows the possibility of holes in the black body, 0's surrounded by 1's. So it's not a single enclosed surface? Also, do you want to store all the distances at the same time? How about calculating the distance of point on the fly(when needed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, given an arbitrary body as the ameba-like shown below, you would like to find the shortest distance from its containing points (for instance, the black point in the figure below) to the edges of the black body. This is the distance shown in blue. And you would like to hopefully take advantage of the orthogonal distances already calculated (black straight lines in the figure) to find it quickly.

[image]

Since the shape is arbitrary and not many assumptions can be made about it, the only thing I could think of is to confine the search for the shortest distance to the bounding square shown below in green. The value of the green square side is two times the shortest orthogonal distance found in your algorithm (from the black point to the green point).

[image]

Another possible approach would be to get instead a 1/8, 1/4 or so of the size of this green square and if no edges are found, keep increasing it until you find one with a few edges. It is guaranteed that at least the last green square will have at least one edge point, which is the orthogonal distance itself.

[image]

Playing with some strategy to grow the green square, maybe you can get a satisfactory performance heuristically.

This solution is easier said than done when it comes to put it in code, but I'm not quite sure I got the problem correctly so I stopped here.

One issue I found is that the term "black body" is not well defined, and the matrix shown in the question does not have any sparse points so it's not random at all as the posted code generates. Does the black body allow holes in it? Even the word "edge" is confusing to me because my English is not very good and the term reminds me of the term used in graph theory which is actually a line segment.

I tried the code and its output seems correct and clear. Just noticed some rubbish is coming out from the not initialized `distances` variable. Easier to get this if you reduce the size of `points` array to 10x10 or so.

EDIT:

Here is a possible implementation of the first method. The function that calculates the shortest distance to the edge, taking into account a bounding square, is the `get_min_dist_to_edge` function. All edges are added to a list to reduce unnecessary checks. To get the first point of the list inside the bounding square, there is no way other than iterating the list from the beginning. In a use case with too many edges, this list can get too large. A hash table containing the elements of the list mapped to its `y` coordinate would allow to find the first element inside the square much faster, at the expense of some memory.

```
#include "ameba.h"

#include <sys/queue.h>
#include <search.h>

#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct point_entry_t {
    int x;
    int y;

    LIST_ENTRY(point_entry_t) entries;
};

LIST_HEAD(slisthead, point_entry_t)
    edges_list_head = LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(edges_list_head);

void add_point_to_edges_list(int x, int y)
{
    static int list_initialized = 0;
    if (list_initialized == 0) {
        LIST_INIT(&edges_list_head);
        list_initialized = 1;
    }

    struct point_entry_t *entry = malloc(sizeof(*entry));
    if (entry) {
        entry->x = x;
        entry->y = y;
        LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&edges_list_head, entry, entries);
    }
}

void clear_list(void)
{
    while (!LIST_EMPTY(&edges_list_head)) {

        struct point_entry_t *n1 = LIST_FIRST(&edges_list_head);
        LIST_REMOVE(n1, entries);
        free(n1);
    }
}

int min(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int e = a < b ? a : b;
    int f = c < d ? c : d;
    int r = e < f ? e : f;
    return r;
}

int calc_distances(unsigned char points[80][80], int distances[80][80][5])
{
    int width = 80;
    int height = 80;

    // scanning in four direction to check if the previous neighbour exists
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    distances[x][y][0] = distances[x - 1][y][0] > 0 ? distances[x - 1][y][0] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][0] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (x < width - 1)
                {
                    distances[x][y][1] = distances[x + 1][y][1] > 0 ? distances[x + 1][y][1] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (y > 0)
                {
                    distances[x][y][2] = distances[x][y - 1][2] > 0 ? distances[x][y - 1][2] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][2] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                if (y < height - 1)
                {
                    distances[x][y][3] = distances[x][y + 1][3] > 0 ? distances[x][y + 1][3] + 1 : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    distances[x][y][3] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // finding the minimum of four distances
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (points[x][y] > 0)
            {
                distances[x][y][4] = min(distances[x][y][0], distances[x][y][1], distances[x][y][2], distances[x][y][3]);

                if (distances[x][y][4] == 1)
                    add_point_to_edges_list(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_edges_and_points(int point_x, int point_y,
                            int min_dist_edge_x, int min_dist_edge_y,
                            int distances[80][80][5])
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < 80; y++) {

        for (size_t x = 0; x < 80; x++) {

            if (   x == min_dist_edge_x
                && y == min_dist_edge_y) {

                printf("E");

            } else if (distances[x][y][4] == 1) {

                printf(".");

            } else if (   x == point_x
                       && y == point_y) {

                printf("P");

            } else {

                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

static inline void get_boundaries(int x, int y, int distances[80][80][5],
                                  int *boundary_start_x, int *boundary_finish_x,
                                  int *boundary_start_y, int *boundary_finish_y)
{
    *boundary_start_x = x - distances[x][y][4];
    *boundary_start_y = y - distances[x][y][4];

    *boundary_finish_x = x + distances[x][y][4];
    *boundary_finish_y = y + distances[x][y][4];

    if (*boundary_start_x  <  0) *boundary_start_x  =  0;
    if (*boundary_start_y  <  0) *boundary_start_y  =  0;
    if (*boundary_finish_x > 80) *boundary_finish_x = 80;
    if (*boundary_finish_y > 80) *boundary_finish_y = 80;

}

float get_min_dist_to_edge(int x, int y, int distances[80][80][5],
                           int *edge_x, int *edge_y)
{
    uint32_t min_sq_dist = INT_MAX;

    int boundary_start_x; int boundary_finish_x;
    int boundary_start_y; int boundary_finish_y;
    get_boundaries(x, y, distances,
                   &boundary_start_x, &boundary_finish_x,
                   &boundary_start_y, &boundary_finish_y);

    if (!LIST_EMPTY(&edges_list_head)) {
        struct point_entry_t *entry = NULL;
        LIST_FOREACH(entry, &edges_list_head, entries) {

            if (   entry->y > boundary_finish_y
                || entry->x < boundary_start_x
                || entry->x > boundary_finish_x) {
                continue;
            } else if (entry->y < boundary_start_y) {
                return sqrt(min_sq_dist);
            }
            int sq_dist = pow(abs(x - entry->x), 2) +
                          pow(abs(y - entry->y), 2);
            if (sq_dist < min_sq_dist) {

                *edge_x = entry->x;
                *edge_y = entry->y;
                min_sq_dist = sq_dist;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int nargs, char *argv[])
{
    if (nargs != 3) {

        printf("\tusage: %s <x> <y>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char (*points)[80] = (unsigned char (*)[80])ameba_bin;
    int distances[80][80][5] = {0,}; // 0 left 1 right 2 bottom 3 top 4 min

    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    int y = atoi(argv[2]);
    int min_dist_edge_x = 0;
    int min_dist_edge_y = 0;

    calc_distances(points, distances);

    float min_dist_edge = 0;
    if ((min_dist_edge = get_min_dist_to_edge(x, y, distances, &min_dist_edge_x,
                                              &min_dist_edge_y)) > 0) {

        print_edges_and_points(x, y, min_dist_edge_x, min_dist_edge_y, distances);
    
        printf("ortho distances for P (%d, %d): < %d, > %d, ^ %d, v %d\n", x, y,
               distances[x][y][0], distances[x][y][1],
               distances[x][y][2], distances[x][y][3]);
    
        printf("min distance from P (%d, %d) to nearest edge point E (%d, %d) = %.02f\n", x, y,
               min_dist_edge_x, min_dist_edge_y, min_dist_edge);
    }

    clear_list();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an output example:

```
$ gcc main.c -lm && ./a.out 35 40

                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                           .....                                
                                       ....     .....                           
                                     ..              ..                         
                                   ..                  ..                       
                                  .                      .                      
                                 .                        .                     
                                .                          .                    
                               .                            .                   
                              .                             .                   
                              .                              .                  
                              .                              .                  
                             .                               .                  
                             .                                .                 
                             .                                .                 
                             .                                .                 
                             .                                 .                
                             .                                 .                
                             .                                 .                
                             .                                  .               
                             .                                  .               
                            .                                   .               
                            .                                    .              
                           .                                     .              
                           E                                      .             
         ........         .                                        .            
        .        ...     .                                         .            
      ..            .....                                           .           
      .                                                              .          
     .                                                                .         
     .                                                                .         
     .                             P                                   .        
     .                                                                 .        
     .                                                                 .        
     .                                                                  .       
     .                                                                  .       
     .                                                                  .       
     .                                                                  .       
      .                                                                 .       
      .                                                                 .       
       .                                                               .        
       .                                                               .        
        .                                                              .        
         .                                                             .        
         .                                                            .         
          .                                                           .         
           .                                                          .         
            .                                                        .          
             ..                                                      .          
               .                                                    .           
                ..                                                  .           
                  ...                                              .            
                     ...                                          .             
                        ...........                              .              
                                   ....                         .               
                                       ..                      .                
                                         ...                  .                 
                                            ...             ..                  
                                               ....      ...                    
                                                   ......                       
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
ortho distances for P (35, 40): < 31, > 37, ^ 28, v 24
min distance from P (35, 40) to nearest edge point E (27, 33) = 10.63
```

[`ameba.h`](https://www.codepile.net/pile/Z130oyDN) was created using `xxd -i` over the output of [a web-based tool](https://www.dcode.fr/binary-image) that converts images to an ASCII table.

Comment: You have well spotted the problem. In the last image, we can check the horizontal and vertical distances from the middle points on small and large green rectangles. From them, we can find the blue point is not inside the small rectangle but within the large rectangle. Therefore, we just need to scan the top left quarter of the difference between the small and large rectangle. I look for the algorithm to do so.

Comment: @Googlebot I added a possible implementation to the answer. It looks cool but there's no benchmarking at all.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called "Euclidean Distance Transform". It can be solved exactly in O(NM) time. Here you can find a nice paper discussing the algorithm.

http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/S62.12/docs/Meijster_distance.pdf

It works also for other norms like Manhattan or Chessboard distance.